# Double entries in Launchpad (Mac OSX 10.7, Lion)

Tags: macos, launchpad

I have many double entries in Launchpad.[image: see screenshot] (Address Book, DVD Player, Image Capture). Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: do you by chance have a dual boot setup? (for example your Snow Leopard install on a second partition)

Comment: If I really want to, I can, but I don't want to go through too much pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launchpad looks for applications in at least two different locations: the Applications folder in your Home directory, and the "root" Applications folder sitting in "Macintosh HD." If it sees an application in more than one place, it puts an icon on the Launchpad for each place it's in. (Try using Spotlight to see if you have more than one Address Book!)

Moving the extraneous apps out of ~/Applications should put them out of Launchpad's sight (at least, as of the next reboot).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I know now what happend: There was a time when I rearranged applications to sub-folders like "media" ...
Everything that has been moved so such a folder has now been newly installed in the default location...