# Change folder name on launchpad?

Tags: macos, mac, launchpad

I'm rearranging my launchpad and I can't seem to figure out how to change the name of one of my folders with the yosemite update.

Answer (score 1):

Simply click the folder, then click the header name, background goes white. Another click will change to an insert point [standard text caret], for finer editing

[image]

Comment: im trying that and it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: might be permissions - is your account an admin account?

Comment: yeah, its an admin account, its the only account i have on the mac.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18630/can-i-choose-the-name-of-a-folder-in-launchpad?rq=1 might be worth a look at